# UI Router - State transition delay (very slow)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I'm using `ui-router` in an angular application and for the vast majority of cases it is working with no problem.

There is case tough where `$state.go("my-state")` doesn't fire an immediat transition. Sometimes it is just very slow (transition to "my-state" after a couple of seconds) sometimes it doesn't fire until I move the mouse around for a while and I fire some event handler (absolutely not related to the event handler that fired the transition).

This is what I have within my directive:

```
// [...]
link: funtcion(scope, elm, attrs){
    elm.on('mouseenter', function(){
            // ...
        })
        .on('mousemove', function($event){
            // ...
        })
        .on('mouseleave', function(){
            // ...
        })
        .on('change', function(){
            // ...
        })
        .on('click', (e) ->

            if(someCondition){
                e.preventDefault()
                e.stopImmediatePropagation()
                e.stopPropagation()

                if(user.level == "visitor"){
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('showLogin')
                }
                else if(user.level == "member") 
                    $('#elementId').remove()
                    // PROBLEM HERE:
                    $state.go("my-state")
            }

            else if(anotherCondition){
                $('#elementId').remove()
            } 
        )
}
// [...]
```

Am I missing something?
Is there anything I can do to "force" ui-router to start the transition?

Comment: Is `$('#eementId')` removed directly after click?

Comment: yes but it is not the element to which the directive is attached to, it is another element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the `element`'s `'on'` event is outside of angular's digest loop.
Update the code where you need the redirection like this:

```
else if(user.level == "member") {
    scope.$apply(function() {
        $('#elementId').remove()
        // PROBLEM HERE: 
        $state.go("my-state")
    });
}
```

`scope.$apply` is used specially for cases like this one where you need to manually invoke angular's digest cycle.

There's one more thing though.
In case an error occurs saying that "digest loop is already in progress" you can use this technique with `$timeout`:

```
else if(user.level == "member") {
    $timeout(function() {
        $('#elementId').remove()
        // PROBLEM HERE: 
        $state.go("my-state")
    });
}
```

But keep in mind that using `$timeout` in this way is considered as a kind of hack and it might be better to find ways around it, but it's still widely used.

**P.S.** do not forget to include `$timeout` as a dependency to the directive definition function.

P.P.S. read more on digest loops [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) and [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/)

Comment: You can use `$applyAsync()` just like `$apply()` and avoid the digest problems since the function will be executed in the next tick (similar to the timeout with 0). [Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$applyAsync)

Answer (score 2):

There is an interesting problem with switching routes if you have large ng-repeat lists in a template. Loading the new view can be delayed. In my case it was up to 7 seconds! A solution I found was to remove the HTML nodes in the list first before switching views. This way UI Router is not unloading the heavy HTML page. In this example clinicList is the parent node of a long list.

```
var clinicList = document.getElementById('clinicList');
if (clinicList) document.getElementById('clinicList').innerHTML = '';
$state.go('selectshiftlistview');
```